# Why my code every time echo `Not right` while it needs to echo `right`?

Tags: php, html

This is my PHP code. When I upload any files with .jpg or .png extensions, i am storing the file extension in `$lower_img_extension` and I did checked it storing `jpg`
Whoever i am getting result  `NOT RIGHT` while the result should be `RIGHT`.
 What am I missing?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    print_r($_FILES["myfile"]);
    echo "<br>";
    $name=$_FILES["myfile"]["name"]."<br>";
    $tem_image=$_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $store="upload/".$name;
    $arr_img=explode(".",$name);
    $lower_img_extension=end($arr_img);
    if(empty($lower_img_extension))
    {
        echo "yes, is empty";
    }
    else
    {
        if($lower_img_extension=='jpg' || $lower_img_extension=='JPG')
        {
            echo "RIGHT";
        }
        else{
            echo "NOT RIGHT";
        }
    }
}
?>

this is my html code:-
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myfile" ></br>
        <input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `$lower_img_extension` name is misleading because it might be capitalized. Also JPEG files can be `.jpg`, `.jpeg` and other variants. Also how is this supposed to test for PNG files?

Comment: You are appending `<br>` to the end of the name, so check for `jpg<br>` instead. Or look for a better way to do it, like appending `<br>` after your  `if / else` :)

Comment: Don't check only extensions, use MIME TYPES too, so a `something.php.jpeg` don't mess your code !

Comment: when the file extension is not empty then i supposed to test the condition in else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use any one method to get extension type from below code and then check if it matches with the type you wish user to upload

```
$image = $FILES[image_name]['type'];
$path = substr("$image",6); // this gives you a image extension
or 
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

Answer (score 0):

An if condition isn't doing what you think it should do?

Add a `var_dump` to your code before the `if` to make sure the variable you're evaluating contains what you think it does.

```
var_dump($lower_img_extension);
if($lower_img_extension=='jpg' || $lower_img_extension=='JPG') ...
```

In this case, *it doesn't*, because you added something else to it earlier in your code, here:

```
$name=$_FILES["myfile"]["name"]."<br>";
```

This probably isn't the best way to check the file type, as someone mentioned in the comments. But in general you should try things like this to help yourself figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: when i removed <br> from $name=$_FILES["myfile"]["name"]."<br>";

Comment: You're welcome! However, I really wanted to emphasize how to start debugging problems like this rather than the specific fix. Sometimes you just have to take a closer look. Good luck with your project. :)